# How to create function to check if at least one checkbox is checked?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<div class="form-group">
<div class="row" style="margin-top: 10px;">
<div class="weekDays-selector checkbox-inline" 
     ng-repeat="day in vm.days" 
     ng-if="vm.pen.feeding_frequency.name == 'Custom'">
<input type="checkbox" ng-click="function()"
       id="custom_frequency{{$index}}" 
       name="custom_frequency" 
       class="weekday" / >
<label for="custom_frequency{{$index}}">{{day.name}}</label>
</div>
```

This is my HTML part for displaying checkboxes based on my object

Object looks like this:

```
vm.days = [{
            name: i18nFilter('_custom_day_monday_'),
            value: 1
        }, {
            name: i18nFilter('_custom_day_tuesday_'),
            value: 2
        }, {
            name: i18nFilter('_custom_day_wednesday_'),
            value: 3
        }, {
            name: i18nFilter('_custom_day_thursday_'),
            value: 4
        }, {
            name: i18nFilter('_custom_day_friday_'),
            value: 5
        }, {
            name: i18nFilter('_custom_day_saturday_'),
            value: 7
        }, {
            name: i18nFilter('_custom_day_sunday_'),
            value: 7
        }]
```

So all I need is just to check if any of these checkboxes created from ng-repeat are checked. Any idea how to do that?

Comment: where is a `ng-model` for checkbox in your `ng-repeat`?

Comment: That literally is a problem, because ng-repeat will generate same ng-model for each box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you modify the checkbox like follow

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="custom_frequency{{$index}}" ng-model="vm.selected[$index]" ng-init="vm.selected[$index]=false" name="custom_frequency" on class="weekday" / >
```

you will get a scope variable called selected inside your vm object. The Object by default will have 7 false values. If you checked one week day then the corresponding index of object updated with true value.....

then you can filter this array to get number of item checked using following code in ts file

```js
var found = Object.keys($scope.vm.selected).filter(function(key) {
    return $scope.vm.selected[key] === true;
  });
console.log(found.length)
```

Answer (score 0):

Get all the checkbox using document.querySelector and use array `some` to check if any them is checked

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll('.weekday')].some(item => item.checked)
```

Comment: To be honest, i'm not really sure how to implement this in my function

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `:checked` selector:

```
document.querySelectorAll(".weekday:checked").length;     // 0 if none is checked
```

Comment: Is there anyway i can get list of checked boxes?

Comment: @ChampagneSupernova yes. `document.querySelectorAll(".weekday:checked")`  is a NodeList

Comment: Did you mean .day instad of "weekday?" weekday is just a class i used for css, day in vm.days is object i gotta check

Comment: number 
NodeList []
length: 0
__proto__: NodeList this is what i get

Comment: Anyways, why don't you store a `totalChecked` inside your Angular state? The above is plain JS to get a NodeList collection of elements, not sure though it's exactly what you desire... Or something like Deepu suggested in his answer.